# Basic JS loading screen issue (not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.styles.css">
    <script src="test_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="LOADER"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#LOADER{
    background-color: #051755;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.Invisible {
    z-index: -1 !important; 
    opacity: 0 !important;
```

```
let $Loader = document.querySelector('#LOADER')

window.addEventListener('load', invisibility); 

function invisibility(){
    $Loader.classList.add('.Invisible');
}
```

Hi, so I was doing a a really basic loader on my webpage that is really simple for my level.
At first I thought that specificity is the issue but prioritizing the invisible class does not help.
Can I get some help? Thank you in advance.

Increasing specificity, rechecked the code but the JS should work and it is not. Also the JS is linked to the html file so that should not be the issue(there are other JS that do work).
I checked the recommended posts but none answered, that in this version with event listener why it does not work to my best knowledge 'load' is and event that happens when the website is loaded.

Comment: `$Loader.classList.add('Invisible')` (without the leading dot).

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: Put `let $Loader = document.querySelector('#LOADER')` inside your `invisibiliy` function because it gets executed before the DOM is ready causing the element to be `undefined`

Comment: The event you looking for is not `load` but `DOMContentLoaded`. Then you must use the querySelector within the eventListener or use a defer attribute as otherwise you get a TypeError or RefereneError with `Element is Null`